# Android canvas paint can't set dark color

Tags: android

I am working on paint application, where I have set layout background in white color and I set the paint color as black. But, in canvas I am getting transparent black color, I want it to be dark color for canvas paint.

my output is below screenshot:

[image]

and my code is below:

```
public DrawView(Context context){
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);      
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0x80808080);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
    mCanvas = new Canvas();
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem

Comment: You should [accept answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) that helped you.

Comment: you should go with [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

**instead of**

```
mPaint.setColor(0x80808080);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Paint has a alpha channel set to slightly transparent. Insert this line.

```
mPaint.setAlpha(255);
```